# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an executable program or a batch file

Tags: pandas, cmd, pip, command, internals

"'pip' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an executable program or a batch file."
Igot this error when I tried to install pandas in python 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

On a windows machine to install a package open a CMD window in the python installation directory.

Then type "Python -m pip install pandas"

```
Python -m pip install pandas
```

please let me know if this works for you.